# If variable is false will it be passed over in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If `co.chkShowRSB` is false, what is the expected result? I would expect it to be false, but is this the way it works? And why?

`var test = chkShow:co.chkShowRSB || true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you got the picture by now `x = false || true;` assigns true. Why? It's quite easy knowing the use of the *short-circuit-operator* is the same as doing:

```
x = (false ? false : true);
```

However, it's mostly used to set default values for function arguments, so I'm guessing you're assuming `x` to be assigned the second operand if the first is `undefined`. There is no way to  filter out undefined values exclusively except for explicitly  checking for them. You should then use:

```
x = val === undefined ? defaultVal : val;
```

Or, because `undefined` needn't be `undefined`, and you want to be *absolutely* sure:

```
x = (function(val,undefined)//second argument will be the true undefined value
{
    return (val === undefined ? defaultVal : val);
})(val);//don't pass second argument
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `true` in your case, as `true` is the second operand of `||` (so-called 'short-circuit or') operator. The common rule is...

```
var x = a || b; // = a (and b won't be evaluated), if it's a truthy value, b otherwise
var y = a && b; // = a (and b won't be evaluated), if it's a falsy value, b otherwise.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
false || true
```

is true. There is no case where a boolean term with "or true" can be false.

Answer (score 0):

you should use tertiary operator.  your code will always return true if chkShow:co.chkShowRSB is boolean;

```
var test =  chkShow:co.chkShowRSB == false ? false : true;
```

Comment: Or just `!!chkShow:co.chkShowRsb`.

Comment: that would return false instead of true if it was undefined. Interesting never the less.